unitywebrequest only failing with certain inputs
My unitywebrequest is only working if I put a certain amount of characters in it, else I get the error HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.
For example:
using UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(website, "{ \"body\": \"loginUser=fjkixrx&loginPass=secretpassword&thirdoption=example data\"}");

This will work, yet this:
using UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(website, "{ \"body\": \"loginUser=different&loginPass=secretpassword&thirdoption=example data\"}");

won't work. I figured out that loginUser needs to have exactly 7 characters, but I can't comprehend how. I'm sending this to a lambda function. In the lambda function I can change it around with anything in the test and it works. Why would only certain things work? Where do I even begin to look for a solution?
I don't think it is useful, but here is my lambda_handler() function.
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Extract form data from the POST request"""
    print("Received third option data:")
    form_data = parse_form_data(event)
 
    # Process the form data (you can customize this part based on your needs)
    if 'loginUser' in form_data and 'loginPass' in form_data:
        login_user = form_data['loginUser']
        login_pass = form_data['loginPass']
        print(f"Received login credentials - User: {login_user}, Password: {login_pass}")
 
    if 'thirdoption' in form_data:
        third_option = form_data['thirdoption']
        print(f"Received third option data: {third_option}")
 
 
    # Return a response
    return {
         'statusCode': 200,
         'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Form data received successfully'})
     }
 
def parse_form_data(event):
    """Parse form data from the event object"""
    form_data = {}
    if 'body' in event:
        body = event['body']
        form_data = {k: v for k, v in [param.split('=') for param in body.split('&')]}
    return form_data

Putting magical numbers and simplifying the lambda function helped me pinpoint the exact problem. The error though doesn't give me anything more to go off of, and so I don't know what else to turn to.

I figured out that it is encoded. The reason that only that certain string was working was because it just accidently was able to bypass the security.

import base64 import urllib.parse
def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Decode the base64-encoded body
if event.get('isBase64Encoded'):
decoded_body = base64.b64decode(event['body']).decode('utf-8')
else:
decoded_body = event['body']
# Parse the form data
form_data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(decoded_body)

# Extract loginUser and loginPass
login_user = form_data.get('loginUser', [None])[0]
login_pass = form_data.get('loginPass', [None])[0]

# Your logic here
print(f'User: {login_user}, Pass: {login_pass}')

# Return a response
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': f'User {login_user} logged in successfully'
}


this was the fixed code in the lamba expression that will be able to decode it.
